# pause current ajax call , carry out a new one , after carrying out , continue the default ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm not sure this is possible.

I have two ajax calls executed during a button click event.
first ajax call is to add data to database using jquery ajax post .
the second one is to add another set of data to database too via jquery ajax post too

The first one will execute first then the second one. i have set a **timer to the second call**(windowstimeout) to create a time interval between both execution to test if i can pause the first ajax call.

You will be asking me why i don't want to combine both calls. i have the reasons to do, and i want to know is it really possible to pause an ajax call. I have search around the net , all i found is the ajaxstop(jQuery) but it don't really pause it , it stops the ajax call.

SO anyone have any idea to do so? Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you just placing your second async postback in the success callback of the first request?

Comment: Not literally, no.  This is request/response behavior issue, not a javascript one really.

Comment: Once the call goes out to the server-side it is out of the hands of the client. you can't tell the server to pause mid way, you could hold the result of the first until the second completes, or nest the second call within the first. Could you expand on what you are trying to do with this pause?

Comment: oh i see. so there's no way to pause it then. thanks

Comment: well im on a platform , the platform have a button , when user click on it , it will sends an ajax call(default) , but i have another new ajax call using javascript (putting onclick="ajaxcall2();" ) to the button attributes . but the first one is always faster than the second one . once the first one is sent , the page will refresh(default) , my second call is still in the way of sending to database.

Comment: so my second one cant be sent as the page already reloaded. :(

Comment: How about setting a boolean value indicating if the second request has completed and kick off the refresh after it is set to true (use a timeout loop on the first which wakes and checks the value)

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to pause it? You can't, but why would you want to? Just let them both run, or don't trigger the first call till the second is done.

Comment: just to find out is there a technique can do that. i guess not then.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot pause Ajax calls - they are just instances of the normal HTTP request/response cycle and behave as such. If the server-side operations resulting from the second call depend on the results of the first one, then why don't you just chain the calls and trigger the second one in the first's success callback handler?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that.

You should really ask yourself if the design of your data exchange protocol is correct.

Pausing a request (whatever the communication protocol is, AJAX or any other) should not work since you cannot know if there are other requests and what they do.

So ask yourself the questions: what is my exact need ? what are the other ways to do that ?